# Fill area under curve in the right order

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

Good evening. I am building a plot for a data which was recorded over a year. For this frequency analysis I want to add thresholds to show at which time these have been passed. The area under these thresholds should be colored in red, orange and green but without to overlay the next area above. I thought to achieve this via the fill-command at the line of \addplot command but this doesn't have any effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}
\usepackage{luatex85,shellesc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[area style,
                width=16.5cm,
                height=7cm,
                date coordinates in=x,
                date ZERO=2013-01-01,
                xmin=2013-01-01,
                xmax=2013-12-29,
     
            ]
       \addplot[color=black!70, thick] coordinates {
    (2013-01-01,10) %Data for the year
    (2013-01-02,13)
    ...
    (2013-12-28,14)
    (2013-12-29,18)
       };
    \addplot[fill=green!30,color=green, thick] coordinates
            {(2013-01-01,10) (2013-12-29,10)}; %Threshold 1
    \addplot[fill=orange!30,,thick] coordinates
            {(2013-01-01,15) (2013-12-29,15)}; %Threshold 2
    \addplot[fill=red!60,color=red,thick] coordinates
            {(2013-01-01,20) (2013-12-29,20)}; %Threshold 3
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The current above result into the following outcome without any filled area under a curve:[image: Current outcome]

Instead, I want to achieve the following outcome: [image: Target output]

Is there a more promising approach to get the outcome as shown in the second picture by filling the area under the curve and in right order so that the colors are not overlaying?

Comment: Which TikZ libraries are you using? I can't run your code…

Comment: My plot-related preamble only consists of
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

Comment: Please, extend your code snippet to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce showed diagram. So far your code fragment is not compilable.

Comment: I extended the snippet above to an mwe.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately your MWE doesn't work. Meanwhile I write the following MWE, which can serve you as starting point. Note, that for filling of area is used pgfplots library `fillbetween`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,
                    dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
lbl/.style = {text=#1,font=\huge\bfseries,midway,below}
                       ]
\begin{axis}[%area style,
    width=16.5cm,
    height=7cm,
%    date coordinates in=x,
%    date ZERO=2013-01-01,
%    xmin=2013-01-01,
%    xmax=2013-12-29,
        ]
\addplot [color=red,   thick, name path=A]  
            coordinates { (0,1 ) (1,1 )} node[lbl=red] {Red};
\addplot [color=orange,thick, name path=B]  
            coordinates { (0,.6) (1,.6)} node[lbl=orange] {Orange};
\addplot [color=green, thick, name path=C] 
            coordinates { (0,.4) (1,.4)} node[lbl=green] {Green};
\addplot [draw=none, name path=Axis]   coordinates { (0,0) (1,0)};
% fill
\addplot [red!20]     fill between [of=A and Axis];
\addplot [orange!20]  fill between [of=B and Axis];
\addplot [green!20]   fill between [of=C and Axis];
% your function
% \addplot <your function>
%
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With some simplifications of diagram code and consideration of the OP comment:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
% abbreviations for use of axis minimal and maximal values
     \newcommand\Xmin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}
     \newcommand\Xmax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,
                    dateplot}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
lbl/.style = {font=\huge\bfseries,midway,below},
                      ]
 \begin{axis}[%area style,
    width=16.5cm,
    height=7cm,
    axis on top,
    enlargelimits=false,
%    date coordinates in=x,
%    date ZERO=2013-01-01,
%    xmin=2013-01-01,
%    xmax=2013-12-29,
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    domain=0:10, samples=101,
    no marks,
    every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick, color=blue, semitransparent},
        ]
\draw[red,      name path=A] (\Xmin,2.0) -- node[lbl] {Red}     (\Xmax,2.0);
\draw [orange,  name path=B] (\Xmin,1.4) -- node[lbl] {Orange}  (\Xmax,1.4);
\draw [green,   name path=C] (\Xmin,0.8) -- node[lbl] {Green}   (\Xmax,0.8);
\path [name path=Axis] (\Xmin,0) -- node[lbl] {Red} (\Xmax,0);
% fill
%\addplot [red!20]     fill between [of=A and Axis];
\addplot [orange!20]  fill between [of=B and Axis];
\addplot [green!20]   fill between [of=C and Axis];
% function (dummy example)
\addplot    {1+rand};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is there a possibility to avoid the blank space under the green area?

Comment: @TimSqua, yes, it is:  just use `enlargelimits=false,`. See addendum in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the first example works almost perfectly for me. Just one more little question: When I apply the first fill in-solution to my data, the filled area is overlapping the y axis on both sides so that the axis is not visible anymore. When I use the second and second last datapoint as coordinates there remains one small blank space.

Comment: @TimSqua, please compare `axis` options in the first and second solution. Between others the second differ with having `axis on top,`.  Anyway, I suggest you to use second solution or combination axis preamble from second solution with code from the first solution and see, if the result will be what you after.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with filled rectangles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=16.5cm,
    height=7cm,
    date coordinates in=x,
    date ZERO=2013-01-01,
    xmin=2013-01-01,
    xmax=2013-12-29,
    no markers,
    solid
    ]
    \fill [green!30, opacity=.5] (axis cs:2013-01-01, 0) rectangle (2013-12-29,10);
    \fill [orange!30, opacity=.5] (axis cs:2013-01-01, 10) rectangle (2013-12-29,15);
    \fill [red!30, opacity=.5] (axis cs:2013-01-01, 15) rectangle (2013-12-29,20);
    \node at (2013-06-15, 5) [green] {Green};
    \node at (2013-06-15, 12.5) [orange] {Orange};
    \node at (2013-06-15, 17.5) [red] {Red};
%   \addplot table [header=false, col sep=comma] {\jobname.csv};
    \addplot[color=black!70, thick] coordinates {
        (2013-01-01,10) %Data for the year
        (2013-01-02,13)
        (2013-01-03,1)
        (2013-12-28,14)
        (2013-12-29,18)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]